# How do I put data into the datastore of Google's app engine?

Tags: java, database, google-app-engine

I have a little application written in php+mysql I want to port to AppEngine, but I just can't find the way to port my mysql data to the datastore.

How am I supposed to save the data into my datastore? Is that even possible? I can only see documentation for persistence of Java objects, does that mean I have to port my database to a bunch of fake objects, one per line?

Edit: I say fake objects because I don't want to use them, they're just a way to get over a shortcoming of the GAE design.

I have a 30 megs table I need to check on every GET, by using objects I would need to create an object for every row, so I'd have a java class of maybe 45 megs with thousands upon thousands of lines like:

Row Row23423 = new Row (123,346,75,34,"a cow");

I just can't believe this is the only way.

Here's an idea, what about populating the data store by POST-ing the objects one by one? I mean, like the posts in a blog. You write a class that generates and persists the data, and then you Curl the url with the data, one by one. Slow, but it may work?

Comment: what do you mean by "fake" objects?

Comment: they're fake because the system mandates me to create them, they're not objects I want in my code.

Answer (score 4):

How to upload data with the bulk loader is described [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html). It's not supported directly in Java yet, but that doesn't have to stop you - just do the following:

Create an app.yaml that looks something like this:

```
application: myapp
version: upload
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /remote_api
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py
  login: admin
```

Make sure the application name is the same as your Java app's, and the version is *not* the same as the version you're using for Java. Upload this 'empty' app using appcfg.py.

Now, follow the directions for bulk loading in the page linked to above. When it comes time to run the tool, specify the server address with --server=upload.latest.myapp.appspot.com .

Since multiple versions of the same app share the same datastore - even across runtimes - the data uploaded with the Python version will be accessible to the Java one.

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation on the datastore [**here**](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/).

I can't see anything about a raw data-porting service but if you can extract the data from your MySQL database into text files, then it should be relatively easy to write a script to import it into the app engine's data store using the persistence frameworks provided by it.

Your script would take your raw data, convert into a (Java) object model and imprt those Java objects into the store.

Comment: Sorry, I need java. And the documentation did not help me.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't read last lines... so it really has to be with fake objects? :(

Answer (score 0):

Migrating an application to Googles App Engine I think would be quite some task. As you have seen the App Engine does not have a relational database instead it uses [BigTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable). This will likely involve exporting it to Java objects (serialized in some way) and the inserting them.
You say "fake" objects in your post but I as you will have to use Java objects anyway I don't think they would be fake unless you plan on using one set of objects for the migration and a new set for the application.

Answer (score 0):

There is no (good) general answer to the question of how to port a relational application to the GAE datastore, because the notion of "data" is incompatible between the two.  Relational databases are all about the schema.  GAE doesn't even have one.  It's a schemaless persistent object datastore with very specific APIs.  The environment is great for certain types of apps if you're developing from scratch, but it's pretty tricky to port to.

That said, you can import CSV files, as Nick explains, which you should be able to export from MySQL fairly easily.  GAE supports Java and Python "at the same time" using the versions mechanism.  So you can set up your data store in Python, and then run against it for your application in Java.  (A Java version of the bulk loader is under development.)